# expo eas local build: how to avoid downloading gradle.zip?

Tags: java, android, gradle, expo, eas

This question is about a network issue when [Running Expo builds on your own infrastructure with Expo EAS CLI](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/local-builds/).

---

I am trying to run `eas build --platform android --non-interactive --local` but I am facing a network error:

```
...
[PREBUILD] [5/5] Building fresh packages...
[PREBUILD] success Saved lockfile.
[PREBUILD] Done in 36.84s.
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Writing secrets to the project's directory
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Injecting signing config into build.gradle
[CONFIGURE_EXPO_UPDATES] Using default release channel for 'expo-updates' (default)
[RUN_GRADLEW] Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /tmp/root/eas-build-local-nodejs/f1c1ab1b-fe51-4bc9-a46a-bfab5cc8c2f7/build/01_App/frontend/android
[RUN_GRADLEW] Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
[RUN_GRADLEW] Exception in thread "main"
[RUN_GRADLEW] java.io.IOException: Downloading from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip failed: timeout
...
```

However, calling `wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip` works! Therefore, this network issue only happens from within the `eas build` command.

I am running this from a corporate network, and it is not the first time I encounter weird network issues that are hard and tiring to debug. It might be something with DNS resolution, with Docker, with firewall rules, with TLS certificates, I don't know. I've even found another machine from which it works, but I need to run this on this machine.

I'd like to work around this, instead of finding the root cause of the network issue. Since I can download this zip file myself very easily, I was hoping for a way for me to give it to `eas build` so that it doesn't try to download it.

- Maybe by putting the zip file in a specific folder?
- Maybe by doing something with the zip file (unzipping, installing somehow)?
- Something else?

The goal is to make `eas build` decide it does not need to do this. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can overcome the issue easily I guess.

If you can download using a normal browser, Is there any proxy configuration added to your browser so you can access external network?

If yes, Then it's pretty simple.

There are 3 things you can try according to my understanding of this.

***First***,

As you have downloaded the zip, It will contain `Gradle-7.3.3`, If you want, you can add Gradle to the system instant of using the wrapper, Once this is done. You can type `Gradle wrapper` command which will add `gradle/wrapper` folder with valid info and this should be enough to solve the issue.

***Second***,

You can manually configure, by copying the file needed into the path.

This can be found in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` which looks like this

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

So what you have to do is, go to `wrapper/dists` and copy the zip file, and the build system will check that it is valid and you won't have to download it again.

***Third***,
If there is proxy configuration, Its way easier to set the rules to `gradle/gradle-wrapper`

You can either set the rules globally, or locally by adding this to `gradle.properties` or `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost={PROXY IP}
systemProp.https.proxyPort={PROXY PORT}
systemProp.https.proxyUser={USERNAME}
systemProp.https.proxyPassword={PASSWORD}
```

This will cause either gradle or the wrapper to use the same configuration as your browser with the build, And there should be no issue downloading anymore.